# Non additive noise

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, noise

I understand that additive noise is noise that gets added to any noise that might be intrinsic to the information system.

So what exactly does non-additive noise get added to? 
Can an example of non-additive noise be impulse noise?

Comment: Not sure the context you are refer to so I may be wrong but I see it like this: Additive noise is added to the useful signal and non-additive noise replace the useful signal. So if you know the properties of the noise for additive signal you can predict its value and remove it from signal to lower the noise/signal ratio. With non-additive noise you predict its position and mask it out then interpolate the missing data instead which leads also to better noise/signal ratio then before but the missing data is still missing ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with programing instead it is theoretical signal processing question